# C: reading file backwards : why this particular method is not considered good?

Tags: c, operating-system

Hi I have a doubt regarding following question: In the OS textbook "**Operating Systems in Depth by Thomas W Doeppner**", one of the chapter exercise questions asks us to find fault with the given code for reading file contents backwards and also asks for a better way to do it. Now I have come across many ways to do that but cant really *find out why the following is not considered a good way of doing it*?

Appreciate your time and help ,thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int fd;
    off_t fptr;
    fd = open("./file.txt", O_RDONLY);
    char buf[3];
    /* go to last char in file */
    fptr = lseek(fd, (off_t)-1, SEEK_END);
    while (fptr != -1) {
        read(fd, buf, 1);
        write(1, buf, 1);
        fptr = lseek(fd, (off_t)-2, SEEK_CUR);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reading one byte at a time is incredibly slow. You have 3 traps to the kernel for every byte read.

Comment: `Read`, `write` and `lseek` are all system calls, and system calls are slow. You would ideally read a lot of data and write a lot of data at once.

Comment: Thank you @zneak for the insights. I will keep this in mind programming forwards.

Comment: Thank you @evaitl for the insights. I will keep this in mind programming forwards.

Comment: This will horrifically break utf-8 (or any other multibyte-encoding, as well as wide-character files).

Comment: @EOF if I am not wrong will this happen because I am reading one byte at a time and characters (like wide characters ) have size greater than traditional 8-bit?

Comment: @Xeqtr: Yes, wide character encodings use more than one byte per character. Actually, utf-16 *might* work after reversing the file, because it's so poorly specified that the endianness of the encoding depends on the platform. utf-16 is *supposed* to have a  marker to specify the endianness at the beginning of the file, but it tends to be omitted. Anyway, utf-8 would *definitely* break.

Comment: @EOF this is amazing, I never thought this way , I will make sure to read regarding these formats and endian systems. Thank you again for this great insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method illustrated in your code is inefficient because you make 3 system calls for each byte in the file.  Furthermore, you do not check the return values of the `read()` and `write()` function calls, nor that the file was opened successfully.

To improve efficiency, you should bufferize the input/output operations.

- Using `putchar()` instead of `write()` would be both more efficient and more reliable.
- Reading a chunk of file contents (from a few kilobytes to several megabytes) at a time would be more efficient too.

As always, benchmark the resulting code to measure actual performance improvements.

Comment: I get the idea now, I am new to the system calls and I should read more about efficiency also , Thank you so much for taking time out and answering.